# Why is this bold text not respecting CSS vertical-align:middle

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I have a bunch of text and images in a line and i want to align vertically.  It all seems to work except I just added some bold text and the bold text seems to show up a little lower than the regular text.

here is a screenshot:

[image]

here is a simpliried view of my html:

```
<span class="midAlign">
    Filter: [<b>Apps: </b>My App Name ]
</span>
```

here is my css:

```
  .midAlign * {vertical-align: middle;}
```

if I remove the bold tag, it seems to line up correctly:

[image]

Comment: There might be some extra css being applied to that <b> tag?

Comment: I viewed in firebug and I don't see any other css at play

Comment: which font family is this? try switching font-family for a min.

Comment: is there any reason as to why you are using the b tag as opposed to <strong> or css font-weight property?

Comment: If you are using custom font-family then you should use its bold version not the b tag bold version.

Comment: as per html5 specs the use of the b tag should be taken as a last resort.

Comment: I tried with <span style="font-weight:bold"> and saw the same issue . .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*I have a bunch of text and **images** in a line*

So when you use `.midAlign *` it applies to all the elements, so the face is you don't need to apply that property to all elements, you need that for `img` only so use

```
.midAlign img {
   vertical-align: middle;
}
```

And it will solve the issue.

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mr_alien/RJj3Z/)</kbd>

Also, when you use the `*` selector, it impacts the performance, you are using that for no good reason for this particular case.

---

I will explain you why that happened. `b` and `img` both are *inline* elements, so when you apply `vertical-align: middle;` it aligns the element to the *baseline*, so say we have an `img` and a `b` tag, so `b` will be vertically aligned middle *considering the entire height of an element*... see this

[image]

---

So when you are using `middle` as the value, it's *middle* but, to the entire element height and not just your text

[image]

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mr_alien/RJj3Z/1/)</kbd>

So technically your `b` tag was aligned middle vertically, but it's just that you don't have to align that, so use specific element selector instead of a generalized `*` selector.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the `.midAlign *` **only** applies to the `<b>` element. Just removing the `*` solves the problem.